# 4 numbers are picked in a row at random...

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> 4 numbers are picked in a row at random from ${1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }$ with replacement.
>
> Let $A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }$
>
> a) Find the probability that all numbers picked are different.

My question:

If we are picking numbers with replacement, then usually order should count right? So if I pick 1, 4, 5, 10 from $A$, then I can place it back and still have 10 possibilities to pick from? But since we're picking in a "row" that means 1, 4, 5, 10 is different from 4, 5, 1, 10?

So that means we have $10^4$ ways to pick 4 numbers, where order counts and with replacement.

But could someone go in depth on why order really matters? And how do you know it does?

Comment: Why are you *worrying* about order?  Order takes care of itself.  There are $10^4$ ways to pick four items (10 for the first, 10 for the second and so one) and $10*9*8*7$ ways to pick four items without repetition.  (10 for the first, 9 for the second, and so on).  So probability if $\frac{10*9*8*7}{10^4}$.  That's all there is to it.  I count $1,4,5,10$ differently for $4,5, 1,10$ because ... it *is* different.

Answer (score 2):

Actually order *does not really matter* but building in an order (e.g. a chronological one) cannot harm and can be useful.

Doing so we can e.g. define $X_k$ as the number of distinct numbers that have been drawn after exactly $k$ picks, and the problem can be solved as:$$P(X_4=4)=P(X_2=2\wedge X_3=3\wedge X_4=4)=$$$$P(X_2=2)P(X_3=3\mid X_2=2)P(X_4=4\mid X_3=3)=\frac{9}{10}\frac{8}{10}\frac7{10}$$

This way of thinking ("I pick one, then I pick a second,.." etc) is a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.   We count the ways to *select* and *arrange* four *distinct* numbers from the set of 10, and divide by the count for ways to *select an arrangement* of any four numbers from the set *with replacement*.

$$\dfrac{\dbinom{10}44!}{10^4} = \dfrac{10\cdot 9\cdot 8\cdot 7}{10^4}$$

---

> But could someone go in depth on why order really matters? And how do you know it does?

Your total count for equally probable outcomes, $10^4$, is the count for ways to make a *sequence* of $4$ selections from $10$ options.   Therefore the outcomes in *this* favoured event should be counted in the same manner: as a sequence of four selections with the given restriction (that they are distinct).  That can be counted either by:

- counting ways to select 4 distinct numbers, and then arranging them, or
- counting ways to make four subsequent selections with the prior choices removed from the options.