# Selecting $3$ red balls out of $3$ red and $2$ blue balls in $4$ trails with replacement

Tags: probability

> Suppose you have $3$ red balls and $2$ blue balls and asked what is the probability that you get $3$ red balls in $4$ trials with replacement.

They way I think is we need to find Combinations of picking balls and divide it by total combinations

Picking 1 st ball $= 3/5$,

Second Ball $= 3/5$,

Third Ball $= 3/5$

4th Ball 
For red $= 3/5$,
For blue $= 2/5$.

Hence the combined probability $= 3/5 \cdot 3/5 \cdot3/5 \cdot(3/5 + 2/5)
= 3/5 \cdot 3/5 \cdot 3/5$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you calculated is the probability that the *first* $3$ balls drawn are red, so your answer is wrong.

---

It is with replacement so there are $4$ independent experiments that all have the same probability to succeed (i.e. the draw results in a red ball). The probability on success is $\frac35$.

Then you are dealing with [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with parameters $n=4$ and $p=\frac35$.

To be found is: $$P(X=3)=\binom43\left(\frac35\right)^3\left(\frac25\right)^1$$

Observe that $\binom43=4$ and is actually the number of possibilities shown in the answer of Robert.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. If I am dealing with Combinatorics why are we worried about order. If order is important this is a probability with Combinatorics if not it should be probability with permutations, isn't it?

Comment: It is just handsome to build in an order here, i.e. to think of the process as picking balls one by one (as you did yourself in your question). Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3135080/75923) and its answers is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have to revise your work. The four trials could be $$BRRR,\quad RBRR, \quad RRBR,\quad RRRB$$ 
(we assume that we need **exactly** $3$ $R$(ed) balls). Instead you considered the cases: $RRRB$ or $RRRR$, that is the first $3$ balls are $R$ed.

What is the probability of each case. What is the combined probability?

Comment: If I have to take combinations why is the order important.

Comment: Note the order will be considered also for the total number of ways: $5^4$.